# bash substitution call that increments a variable

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I'm trying to define a bash function returning an incremented id
that I can access directly using bash substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash

getId() {
        echo "$x"
        x=$((x+1))
}

x=0
echo "id1: $(getId)"
echo "id2: $(getId)"
```

However the variable is not incremented and I cannot figure out why.

> ```
> id1: 0
> id2: 0
> ```

Please, does someone have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Each `$()` is a sub-shell so the assignments aren't happening in the parent shell.

Comment: The answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124904/67134) might be of use here but I'm not sure offhand.

Comment: I also thought it was a sub-shell call but I cannot stat it using strace. However, the result is clearely the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
getId() {
  echo "$x"
  ((x++))
}
x=0
echo -n "id1: "
getId
echo -n "id2: "
getId
```

Output:

```
id1: 0
id2: 1
```

Comment: Instead of using a global variable, you could pass the variable name: `getId() { (($1++)); }; getId x; getId x`

Comment: @user3149355, the return value if a function is only from 0 to 255. Not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way I know of to do it in a sub-shell call using the syntax you have (in the echo line).

An alternate would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

export x=0

incId() {
        #echo "$x"
        (( x += 1))
}

incId
echo "id1: $x"
incId
echo "id2: $x"
```

But here you need the out-of-the-echo-line `incId` function call to get the id incremented.

It also starts counting from 1, not 0.

<strike>Using the `let` shell command is the better way to do math too.</strike>

Using `(( ... ))` is the [right way to do shell arithmetic](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html)

Comment: Thanks, you confirm that I'm not creazy and cannot do it in a one-line call. (and thanks for the let command)

Comment: `let` is an obsolete way to do math; `$((...))` is part of the POSIX standard.

Comment: Well, `((...))` is not POSIX; it's a bash extension, but for the most part `((x+=1))` is just short for `: $((x+=1))`.

Comment: Some ways to increment with bash: `x=0; : $[ x++ ]; ((x++)); x=$((x+1)); let x=x+1; echo $x`

Answer (score 1):

Might as well make it generic:

```
incr() { (( $1 += ${2:-1} )); }
```

Examples:

```
incr x   ; echo $x  # => 1
incr x   ; echo $x  # => 2
incr x  4; echo $x  # => 6
incr x -2; echo $x  # => 4
```